# How to compile C++ application for Unix/Linux in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, g++

I have an application written in C++ using wxWidgets. How can I compile it for Linux and Unix os like Debian, FreeBSD, CentOS, in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the build system used. More info required.

Comment: Are you trying to cross compile on Windows for some unix OSes, or are you trying compile the source code on the target OSes directly?

Comment: yes i tried on the target os directly but i need to compile it on windows for my build system

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if I understood the question, but I think you are asking if you can compile an application for linux using a compiler in the windows environment.

My short answer: No, but.

The but: You may be able to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in windows, however I think there is an easier way. If you are uncomfortable with setting up your computer to have multiple partitions and installing linux on at least one of these partitions, you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/), or similar virtualization software to "install" linux on your windows machine. From there you can set up build environments and such. As for how, I would leave your windows build as is, but then in create a Makefile for Linux (or use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to replace both your windows-specific builder (the vsproj if using visual studio, etc) and linux-specific builder (make)) so that your source will compile both on windows and linux without having to modify the actual code or project.

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) as build system